# NavigateToPose vs NavigateThroughPose

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-bt-navigator.html,
The document show that I need to configure two BT for both NavigateToPose and NavigateThroughPose.

My question is, how will the Nav2 package decide which BT tree to use during navigation? Or will it just choose the best BT at that moment?

Also, I am wondering how will I be able to send my goal to Nav2 package?

Thank you very much in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409833/navigatetopose-vs-navigatethroughpose/) by [sdu568](https://answers.ros.org/users/103946/sdu568/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2022-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on the action server you call. When you launch nav2 both action servers are offered as `/navigate_to_pose` and `/navigate_through_poses`. Names show which BT is used by each.

You can use the [simple commander API](https://navigation.ros.org/commander_api/index.html)  to easily interface your application with nav2. This API already wraps all the ROS2 code needed to use action servers in simple function calls. You can also write your own commander interface directly calling the action servers I mentioned above.

---

Originally posted by [Pepis](https://answers.ros.org/users/66603/pepis/) with karma: 130 on 2022-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdu568](https://answers.ros.org/users/103946/sdu568/) on 2022-11-25**:
Please correct me if I understood wrong.

So basically, in the launch file, we load two BT trees (for both /navigate_to_pose and /navigate_through_poses). And then I will create a node that triggers either one of them.

Thus, does this mean that If I want to have my own BT tree, all I need to do is to reconfigure it in the launch file?

**Comment by [Pepis](https://answers.ros.org/users/66603/pepis/) on 2022-11-25**:
Yes, the easiest thing IMO would be to take one of the BTs and modify it to your needs, then pass its path in the parameters or the launch file